# Is it legal to use LaTeX for restoring old books?

Tags: book-design, tex-general

I wonder if it's legal to use LaTeX for restoring / digitizing of old books?

Let say some old books (from 1950-1980), which have been published in paper only, and can be accessed only in the library or ordered as scan-copy (per chapters).
Also, are there any communities or companies that support such type of activity?

P.S. Is it an appropriate section of StackExchange for such a question?

Comment: if you have rights to the book text you can certainly use latex, so it's not really a tex question. If you get the copy from a library you typically don't have rights to copy, but it all depends..  not on topic here though

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because legal question not on topic here

Comment: [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/) is one such project. If something is legally out of copyright protection, then releasing a new version in any format is permitted. But this is definitely not really a question for the site.